# Fluxbox: Liberate the alt key for a single application

Tags: fluxbox

By default, in fluxbox if you hold down alt and press the left mouse button on a window, you can move it. I like this feature.

But I'm trying to use inkscape, which has its own use for alt. Can I disable the window-moving option for the alt key, whenever the active window is inkscape?

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (mostly mapped to the <kbd>Mod1</kbd> - modifier) is used not only by Inkscape but also by many many many .. many other programs: Gimp, Blender, Browsers, Editors, etc. And not only on Unix but also on Windows and Mac. Thus, I personally use the <kbd>Win</kbd> key as the trigger for most `fluxbox` actions:

```
OnWindow Mod4 Mouse1 :StartMoving
OnWindow Mod4 Mouse3 :StartResizing NearestCorner
```

(part of my `.fluxbox/keys`). You could use some undocumented actions to switch to a different `KeyMode` when the focus switched to Inkscape and switches back to the default behavior when Inkscape loses the focus but in the long term I think that will only confuse your user experience. Use the <kbd>Win</kbd> - key and be happy with it.

Comment: The thing is-- I don't have a win key! I use an old mechanic keyboard, and I wouldn't change it for the world :) What do you mean by undocumented actions?

Comment: they are undocumented for a reason... :) anyway: what other unused keys do you have on your mechanic keyboard? You can also map the left and the right `Alt`-keys to a different modifier (mod1 and mod4) ...